# how do i surround a string with double quotes using bteq

Tags: string, export, teradata

I'm creating a CSV File that is then mailed to a user group.
In this file there is a long varchar() column that has legimate commas in it.

Needless to say, this is throwing off the XLS import.

Is there a way in BTEQ to force double quotes around the string?

I can't seem to get it to print using "\"".  Any other options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.
select ... '"' || field1 || '"' ... from ...